# The events are independent iff $P(B_{1}\cap \dots \cap B_{n})=P(B_{1}) \cap P(B_{2}) \dots P(B_{n})$

Tags: probability

I want to prove that the events $A_{1}, \dots, A_{n}$ are independent iff

$$P(B_{1}\cap \dots \cap B_{n})=P(B_{1}) \cap P(B_{2}) \dots P(B_{n})$$

for $B_{i}=A_{i}$ or $B_{i}=A_{i}^{c}$

Well, I feel that for the case where $B_{i}=A_{i}$ is something obvious by definition, what would it take to put it in the proof, while for the other case, let $A_{1}, \dots, A_{n}$ independent events, note that:

\begin{align*}
  P(A_{1}^{c} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n}^{c}) &= 1-P(A_{1} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n}) \\
   &= 1-[P(A_{1})+ \cdots-P(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n} )] \\
   &= 1-P(A_{1})- \cdots+P(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n} ) \\
   &=(1-P(A_{1}))(1-P(A_{2})) \cdots (1-P(A_{n}))
\end{align*}

And from the last equality one would have, is this a valid reasoning?

The reverse side, I don't know how to give an argument for the first case, while for the second we could assume that $A_{1}^{c}, \dots, A_{n}^{c}$ are independent events, and

\begin{align*}
  P(A_{1} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n}) &= P(A_{1}) + \cdots +P(A_{n}) - P(A_{1} \cup \cdots \cup A_{n}) \\
   &=P(A_{1}) + \cdots +P(A_{n}) -1+ P(A_{1}^{c}) \cdots P(A_{n}^{c})   \\
   &= P(A_{1}) \cdots P(A_{1}) 
\end{align*}

Is this valid again?

It would be of great help to receive a suggestion for the case that was not possible for me, thank you.

Comment: I can't follow your reasoning because your notation is opaque: what exactly is buried in all those "$\cdots$"?  Regardless, all proofs proceed by logical deduction from a set of assumptions to results, invoking definitions and theorems along the way.  For many people there's nothing to prove because your statement *is* the definition.  Please, then, state what definition of independence you are working with.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499206/show-lemma-on-probability-of-n-independent-sets

Comment: Why don't you use induction instead?